# Embed not getting found in a for loop

Tags: python, discord.py

I have this block of code that goes through messages within the channel and looks for an embed. When it finds the embed, I get the following error:

```
line 87, in on_message
embed = message.embeds[0]
IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is the code that is contained in that loop.

```
elif lowered_message.startswith("!cancel"):
        count = 0
        await message.delete()
        async for message in message.channel.history():
            embed = message.embeds[]
            user_test = str(message.author.display_name)
            user_test = embed_search.description.find(user_test)
            count = count + 1
            print(count)
            if user_test == 0:
                embed.message.delete()
                print("yes")
            else:
                print("no")
```

I can't seem to solve the problem. Any help is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: That line is not in your code.  The likely problem is `async for message in message.channel.history():`, because by reusing the name, you delete the original `message`.

Comment: Carter, the error message is perfectly clear, the message you are checking doesn't have any embeds, hence `message.embeds` is an empty list.